# Is it possible to use C++Builder and CMake to create Python modules?

Tags: python-3.x, swig, c++builder, dllimport, dllexport

C++Builder's 32-bit compiler, bcc32, by default creates shared libraries using the cdecl calling convention, prefixing exported functions with an underscore, 
 e.g. '_functionName'. Visual studio, on the other hand, don't prefix exported functions.

Python, when importing a pyd module, expects a function named PyInitialize_modulename. Since bcc32 prefix this function with an underscore, rendering it to be _PyInitialize_modulename, Python will not be able to import a bcc32 created module.

Using CMake, does anyone know how to add a module definition file, .def, to alias the prefixed function, to an 'unprefixed' one, when compiling/creating the pyd module?

*Update.* In response to Mr. Lebeau's answer below (as a comment);
This question is not about CTypes, but SWIG. CTypes allows for a simple way to wrap a C/C++ DLL, but mainly deals with C structures and POD data.

Swig, on the other hand, allows a client to get object oriented objects in Python, analogous to the ones exported from a C++ DLL. Swig can do this as it process C++ headers.

Swig does create a C++ file that is compiled into a .pyd file (in essence a DLL as noted). The first exported function that Python looks for when trying to load it as a module, is **Pyinit_MyModule** (Python 3). When using C++ Builder, this function is exported as **_Pyinit_MyModule**, as mentioned. Problem is that it is Swig that exports this function, and I can't as a client of Swig change the calling convention (afaik) for this function.

I believe my initial belief that Python needed __stdcall for this functions is wrong, as VS by default is using cdecl, but without adding the '_', and it that works fine.

However, setting the compiler flag to suppress underscores don't work either, as then some of the functions in the Python import libraries are rendered invisible, and become unresolved externals. So perhaps this problem is more complex than it may first look. But I guess it has nothing todo with calling conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling around, I can say that it is possible to create Python extensions using the C++ Builder compiler, swig and CMake.

Below is a brief overview of the steps that I used to wrap a simple C++ class (ATObject) to Python37.

The C++ header file is:

```
#ifndef atATObjectH
#define atATObjectH
#include <string>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
using std::string;
int MyTest(int r);

class ATObject
{
    public:
                                ATObject();
        virtual                 ~ATObject();
        virtual const string    getTypeName() const;
};
#endif
```

and source

```
#pragma hdrstop
#include "core/atATObject.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ATObject::ATObject()    {}
ATObject::~ATObject()    {}

const string ATObject::getTypeName() const
{
    return "TYPENAME NOT IMPLEMENTED";
}

int MyTest(int r)
{
    return r;
}
```

1) Create import libraries using implip on the Python3 and Python37 dll's. Use implibs flag -aa, to get an import library that C++ builder understands. Put them in the Python37/libs folder.

2) Create the swig interface file that defines which class, functions and data to wrap. The swig interface file:

```
// atexplorer.i
%include "std_string.i"
%include "windows.i"

%module atexplorer
%{    
#include "atATObject.h"
%}

//Expose class ATObject to Python
%include "atATObject.h"
```

3) Create CMake files for the project, using SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY to create the .pyd module, e.g.

```
SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(atexplorer MODULE LANGUAGE python SOURCES
atexplorer.i ${ATAPI_ROOT}/source/core/atATObject.cpp )
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES (atexplorer 
   ${PYTHON_LIB_FOLDER}/Python3_CG.lib
   ${PYTHON_LIB_FOLDER}/Python37_CG.lib
)
```

and make CMake pass the .def file to the linker by adding:

```
set (CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/atexplorer.def)
```

The atexplorer.def file should look like this:

```
EXPORTS
   PyInit__atexplorer=_PyInit__atexplorer
```

4) Compile the project, and confirm that you get a generated **"MyModule"PYTHON_wrap.cxx** and a **MyModule.py** file in your CMake build folder. The  "MyModule"PYTHON_wrap.cxx file contains generated C++ code for the Python module, and the .py file contain generated Python code. 
The Python module is named atexplorer.

Image below shows what is exported in the _atexplorer.pyd module.

[image: Aliased PyInit function]

Copy the .pyd and the .py files to Pythons site packages folder.

If successful, you will be able to import the module in Python, e.g.

[image]

The screen shot above shows how the module, atexplorer, is imported. It has a function called 'MyTest', that returns whatever its argument is, when executed.

It also has a class, ATObject, for which an object named 'a', is created. Last line prints the output of executing the class member function 'getTypeName()', which simply returns, TYPENAME NOT IMPLEMENTED.

Answer (score 1):

`cdecl` is simply the typical *default* calling convention that every C++ compiler uses.  If you want to use `stdcall` instead, you can certainly do that (makes sense why Python would expect `stdcall` since that is what the Win32 API uses).

In the module's C++ code, you can use `__stdcall` explicitly in the exported function declarations.

Or, you can change the default calling convention in C++Builder's project settings, and then omit any calling convention in the function declarations.

Now, to answer your question - when importing a pyd module, if the module uses `cdecl`, use `ctypes.cdll` to call its functions.  If the module uses `stdcall`, use `ctypes.windll` instead.  This is covered in Python's documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries

> 16.16.1.1. Loading dynamic link libraries
>
> `ctypes` exports the `cdll`, and on Windows `windll` and `oledll` objects, for loading dynamic link libraries.
>
> You load libraries by accessing them as attributes of these objects. **`cdll` loads libraries which export functions using the standard `cdecl` calling convention, while `windll` libraries call functions using the `stdcall` calling convention**. `oledll` also uses the `stdcall` calling convention, and assumes the functions return a Windows `HRESULT` error code. The error code is used to automatically raise an `OSError` exception when the function call fails.

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll

> Is a *.pyd file the same as a DLL?
>
> **Yes, `.pyd` files are dll’s**, but there are a few differences. If you have a DLL named foo.pyd, then it must have a function `PyInit_foo()`. You can then write Python “import foo”, and Python will search for foo.pyd (as well as foo.py, foo.pyc) and if it finds it, will attempt to call `PyInit_foo()` to initialize it. You do not link your .exe with foo.lib, as that would cause Windows to require the DLL to be present.